# Top 5 records category level 1 and top 3 from category level 2 based on TotalVal

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I have a data with 3 fields query

```
level_1 level_2 total_val
A         AA    1
A         AB    8
A         AC    4
A         AD    6
B         BA    1
B         BB    8
B         BC    4
B         BD    6
B         BE    11
B         BF    2
C         CA    23
C         CB    9
C         CD    7
C         CE    12
C         CF    5
```

I want report output like top 2 from leve1_1 and top 3 from level_2 based on totalval

like

```
level_1 level_2 total_val

C         CA    23
          CE    12
          CB    9
B         BE    11
          BB    8
          BD    6
```

how to in ssrs  can any one help

Comment: Does your data come from an SQL query? If so, it might be easiest to rank your data in the query before it gets used by your SSRS report.

Comment: Seems you could use the ssrs built-in feature [Interactive Sort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/add-interactive-sort-to-a-table-or-matrix-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017) to achieve it.